# validate start and end time using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two `date time pickers`, which I get using framework  where I can select `date and time` in the format `"22-04-2014 07:30PM"`.

Now I need to validate the start and end time such that it allows the valid from and to time . Please guide me in doing this using javascript.

If I select start time as 12:30 PM and end time as 6:30 PM, then it is valid but if I select start time as "10:00 AM" and end time as "8:00 AM", it is not valid .

Comment: But it does not work correctly

Comment: Can you take this date like Date object? If yes, you can compare two Date Objects like seconds since 1970
Something like this new Date('2014-04-22 07:30:00').getTime()

Comment: Use timestamps if you can.

Comment: Yes I also have date object need to validate the time

Comment: Please ,check the format: 22-04-2014 07:30PM or 22-04-2014 07:30 PM (space between PM and Date)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/stUbT/)***</kbd>

**WITHOUT USING PLUGINS**
Try this  : 
The event of check button will be as following:

```
$('input.check').click(function(e){
    var startd=$(this).parent('div').find('input:eq(0)').val()
    var endd=$(this).parent('div').find('input:eq(1)').val()
    alert(convertDate2JS(endd)>convertDate2JS(startd))
})
```

Known that :

```
   function convert2JSTime(time){
 //No space between AM|Pm and Time 
 time=time.toLowerCase();
var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));
    if(time.indexOf('am') != -1 && hours == 12) {
        time = time.replace('12', '0');
    }
    if(time.indexOf('pm')  != -1 && hours < 12) {
        time = time.replace(hours, (parseInt(hours) + 12));
    }
    time=time.replace(/(am|pm)/, '');
    if(time.split(':')[0].length===3){
      time=time.substr(1)
    }
    return time;}
```

Convert the whole date = Date+time:

```
function convertDate2JS(datem){
    return datem.split(' ')[0]+' '+convert2JSTime(datem.split(' ')[1])
}
```

Then

```
   if (convertDate2JS(endDate)>convertDate2JS(strartDate)){
       return true;
   } else{
       return false;
   }
```

**UPDATE :**

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/stUbT/

Comment: can u pls explain it as i am a fresher to this technolog

Comment: what no space  , the time is of the format 07:30AM without space between time and AM

Comment: Also while running this code I get this error time.match(...) is null in firebug

Comment: not able to understand whats happening in this code

Comment: why two functions are there function convertDate2JS(datem) and convert2JSTime(time). How to do this in a single function

Comment: One to convert time hh:MM , the other for whole date : dd-mm-yyyy hh:MM .

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9MC4/1/)***</kbd>

#### Using [this plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) I was able to do direct comparison

***jQuery Code***

```
$('#btnCompare').click(function () {
    var from = $('#txtFrom').val();
    var to = $('#txtTo').val();
    if(from > to){
        $('#Msg').text('To date must be greater than from').css('color','red');
    } else{
        $('#Msg').text('Valid').css('color','green');
    }
});
```